# Removing listeners in Electron when using context isolation

Tags: reactjs, electron

How should listeners be removed in Electron when using Context Isolation.

I am using Electron, React, and Express and would like my components to render upon receiving requests at the api endpoints. I am using contextBridge to pass notifications from the main process to the render process. To the best of my knowledge I am mounting/unmounting my listeners in a useEffect function in the renderFile.js, but I suspect that when I pass the 'off' function to the preload.js it sees a new instance of the '0' event, and not a reference to the '0' event that was passed to 'on', therefore not removing the mounted listener. My code produces the following error:

> (node:18884) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
> leak detected. 11 0 listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Here is my code:

main.js

```
  api.get('/0', (req, res) => {
    res.send('0')
      mainWindow.webContents.send('0');
  })
```

preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  on (eventName, callback) {
    ipcRenderer.on(eventName, callback)
  }, 
  off (eventName, callback) {
    ipcRenderer.removeListener(eventName, callback)
  }, 
})
```

renderFile.js

```
  let zero = () => {
    ref.current = ref.current + '0'
    handleChange(ref.current)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    window.electron.on('0', zero)
   
    return () => {
      window.electron.off('0', zero)
    }
  },[])
```

Comment: Commenting here to add that my quick fix was to removeAllListeners when my components rendered and then call the listeners again. This worked for me, but it is a hack solution. I have come across this post which outlines how removing listerns should be achieved. https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/issues/43